# Несколько связанных Combo box в ленточной форме

Tags: java, vaadin

У меня в базе имеется 4 таблица: Филиал(Branch), Подразделения(subdivision), Отдел(department) и Сектор(section). И эти таблицы заполнены с данными. Теперь не могу делать несколько связанных Combo Box, чтоб при выборе значения в главном списке менялись выпадающие значения в другом.
  Ниже приведен код:

```
private FormLayout createTabFilesLayout() {
FormLayout tabLayout = new FormLayout();        
HorizontalLayout hLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
    hLayout.setWidth("-1px");
    hLayout.setHeight("-1px");
    hLayout.setSpacing(true);       
    cBoxBranch = new ComboBox();
    cBoxBranch.setInputPrompt("Филиал");
    cBoxBranch.setWidth("250px");
    cBoxBranch.setHeight("33px");
    cBoxBranch.setImmediate(true);
    cBoxBranch.setNullSelectionAllowed(false);
    cBoxBranch.setInvalidAllowed(false);
    Iterator<Branch> bran = branch.iterator();
    while(bran.hasNext()) {
        Branch rt = bran.next();
        cBoxBranch.addItem(rt);
        cBoxBranch.setItemCaption(rt, rt.getBranch_name().trim());
        if (applicationForm.getId() != null) {
            if (rt.getId_branch().equals(applicationForm.getRecords().getId_branch().getId_branch()))
            {
                applicationForm.getRecords().setId_branch(rt);
            }
        }
    }
    hLayout.addComponent(cBoxBranch);
    binder.bind(cBoxBranch, "id_branch"); 
    tabLayout.addComponent(hLayout);

    cBoxSubdivision = new ComboBox();
    cBoxSubdivision.setInputPrompt("Подразделения");
    cBoxSubdivision.setWidth("250px");
    cBoxSubdivision.setHeight("33px");
    cBoxSubdivision.setImmediate(true);
    cBoxSubdivision.setNullSelectionAllowed(false);
    cBoxSubdivision.setInvalidAllowed(false);
    Iterator<Subdivision> sub = subdivisions.iterator();
    while (sub.hasNext()) {
        Subdivision rt = sub.next();
        cBoxSubdivision.addItem(rt);
        cBoxSubdivision.setItemCaption(rt, rt.getSubdivision().trim());;
        if (applicationForm.getId() != null) {
            if(rt.getId_subdivision().equals(applicationForm.getRecords().getId_subdivision().getId_subdivision())) {
                applicationForm.getRecords().setId_subdivision(rt);
            }

        }
    }

    hLayout1.addComponent(cBoxSubdivision);
    binder.bind(cBoxSubdivision, "id_subdivision");
    tabLayout.addComponent(hLayout1);

    cBoxDep = new ComboBox();
    cBoxDep.setInputPrompt("Отдел");
    cBoxDep.setWidth("300px");
    cBoxDep.setHeight("33px");
    cBoxDep.setImmediate(true);
    cBoxDep.setNullSelectionAllowed(false);
    Iterator<Department> dep = departments.iterator();
    while (dep.hasNext()) {
        Department rt = dep.next();
        cBoxDep.addItem(rt);
        cBoxDep.setItemCaption(rt, rt.getDepartment_name().trim());
        if(applicationForm.getId() != null) {
            if(rt.getId_department().equals(applicationForm.getRecords().getId_department().getId_department())) {
                applicationForm.getRecords().setId_department(rt);
            }
        }
    }
    hLayout2.addComponent(cBoxDep);
    binder.bind(cBoxDep, "id_department");
    tabLayout.addComponent(hLayout2);

    cBoxSec = new ComboBox();
    cBoxSec.setInputPrompt("Сектор");
    cBoxSec.setWidth("300px");
    cBoxSec.setHeight("33px");
    cBoxSec.setImmediate(true);
    cBoxSec.setNullSelectionAllowed(false);
    Iterator<Section> sec = sections.iterator();
    while(sec.hasNext()) {
        Section rt = sec.next();
        cBoxSec.addItem(rt);
        cBoxSec.setItemCaption(rt, rt.getSection_name().trim());
        if(applicationForm.getId()!=null) {
            if(rt.getId_section().equals(applicationForm.getRecords().getId_section().getId_section())){
                applicationForm.getRecords().setId_section(rt);
            }
        }
    }
    hLayout3.addComponent(cBoxSec);
    binder.bind(cBoxSec, "id_section");
    tabLayout.addComponent(hLayout3);
```

В этом случае в выпадающем окне выходят данные, но связка с другими ComboBox нет.
[image: Combo Box с данными]

Далее, создал метод `CreatSubdivisionList() CreatDepartmentList() CreatSectionList()`

```
    private FormLayout createTabFilesLayout() {
    FormLayout tabLayout = new FormLayout();
    cBoxSubdivision = new ComboBox();
    cBoxSubdivision.setInputPrompt("Подразделения");
    cBoxSubdivision.setWidth("250px");
    cBoxSubdivision.setHeight("33px");
    cBoxSubdivision.setImmediate(true);
    cBoxSubdivision.setNullSelectionAllowed(false);
    cBoxSubdivision.setInvalidAllowed(false);
    CreatSubdivisionList();
    tabLayout.addComponent(cBoxSubdivision);
    binder.bind(cBoxSubdivision, "id_subdivision");
    cBoxSubdivision.addListener(this);

private void CreatSubdivisionList()
{
    if (applicationForm.getRecords().getId_branch()!=null)
    {
        subdivisions = SBranchService.getSubdivisionById(applicationForm.getRecords().getId_branch().getId_branch(), app.getDbHelper().getConnectionPool());
        cBoxSubdivision.removeAllItems();
        Iterator<Subdivision> subd = subdivisions.iterator();
        while (subd.hasNext())
        {
            Subdivision rt = subd.next();
            cBoxSubdivision.addItem(rt);
            cBoxSubdivision.setItemCaption(rt, rt.getSubdivision().trim());
            if(applicationForm.getId() !=null) 
            {
                if (rt.getId_subdivision().equals(applicationForm.getRecords().getId_subdivision().getId_subdivision())) 
                {
                    applicationForm.getRecords().setId_subdivision(rt);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

для других тоже аналогичный код. В таком случае в выпадающем окне пусто.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно выбрать Филиал(Branch), а остальных в выпадающем списке появлялись только те подразделения - отдел и сектор которые привязаны к этой Филиале.

Заранее спасибо за любой информации!

Answer (score 0):

Все сильно зависит от того, как связаны между собой данные.
Например, имеется `HashMap`, где ключ-значение в главном `Combox`, а значение- данные второго, то тогда связывание можно сделать примерно так:

```
    Map<String, List<String>> directFilials = new HashMap<>();

    directFilials.put("FirstDir",
            Arrays.asList("Dir1_1", "Dir1_2", "Dir1_3"));
    directFilials.put("SecondDir",
            Arrays.asList("Dir2_1", "Dir2_2", "Dir2_3"));
    directFilials.put("ThirdDir",
            Arrays.asList("Dir3_1", "Dir3_2", "Dir3_3"));
    // Put customary greeting in a cell
    ComboBox<String> dir = new ComboBox("The main CB");

    ComboBox<String> fil = new ComboBox("The dependable CB");

    dir.setItems(directFilials.keySet());
    dir.addSelectionListener(event -> {
        Optional<String> value = dir.getSelectedItem();
        fil.clear();
        fil.setItems(directFilials.get(value.get()));
    });
```